# How to make a picture fly in and out on transitions with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have started making this web.

[image]

I am desperately trying to make my menus to fly-in and out on transitions. I want my menus to fly-in in a certain order starting from top to bottom.

I have updated this question from its original.

html:

```
<div id="flyin">
<form action="WoodEnglish.html" method="get">   
                <input id="Wood" type="image" src="Wood.png" alt="Submit" > 
</form>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  var currWidth = $(window).width();
  console.log(currWidth);

  var startPos = -1;
  var endPos = 1000;
  console.log(endPos);

  $('#flyin').animate({left: endPos},1000);

  $('#Wood, #submit2').click(function () {
        if (this.id == 'Wood') {
            $('#flyin').animate({left: endPos}, 1000);  
        }
        else if (this.id == 'submit1') {
            alert('Submit 2 clicked');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

However there is still two problems with this code

1. is this; var currWidth = $(window).width(); i think. I need my buttons to fly into the screen from out of screen and atm i am not allowed to do that.
2. atm it doesn't wait until the animation is complete before loading the next html on action form.

thx in advance for any contributions

Comment: It has to be somewhat embarrassing to complain about how difficult it is, when you didn't even read the first simple tutorial on the jQuery pages -> http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Will you read the answer below or will you just ignore like the way you ignored the jQuery basics?

Comment: @Brutiquzz Nothing will fly till it has been grounded!! Don't write jQuery code in `<head>` section. The whole motto of jQuery is to provide behaviour to elements which have loaded, are present in DOM and are available for change in behaviour!

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary Nothing wrong in writing it in the `<head>` section. We just need to initialise correctly!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay i figured it out. This will make an image fly from outside the screen to inside the screen and then again fly from inside the screen to outside the screen when you click it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


  $('#flyin').animate({left: "1000px"},1000);

  $('#Wood, #submit2').click(function () {
        if (this.id == 'Wood') {
            $('#flyin').animate({left: "-1000px"}, 1000);  
        }
        else if (this.id == 'submit1') {
            alert('Submit 2 clicked');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have referenced items in the `<head>`, even before they are loaded. Please wrap everything in `document ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var currWidth = $(window).width();
  console.log(currWidth);

  var startPos = -100;
  var endPos = (currWidth / 2) + (startPos / 2);
  console.log(endPos);

  $('#flyin').animate({left: endPos}, 1000);
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/pafigicabo/edit?js,output**

Comment: This does exactly the same. only displaying an image not doing anything.

Comment: Finally you answered! Great, will try editing your code then!

Comment: @Brutiquzz FYKI, it works perfectly fine!!! Check: http://jsbin.com/pafigicabo/edit?js,output What else you need?

Comment: Yes your fiddle works... have you tried running it in chrome cause i am still getting same result. I have even tried adding: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Comment: I am using Chrome 42.xxx. Checked in `Chromium Version 45.0.2420.0` and `Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 m`.

Comment: Okay it works now and thanks for that. However this was not what i was originally asking for. As the titel clearly says then i need my code to make an image to fly in and out on transition. Meaning that when i press a button on my web then components fly out and new ones fly in. 

My code only makes an image fly in and not out again on transition.

Comment: Ah... Could you give me more time as I am in the office?

Comment: take all the time you need sir :)

Comment: I have updated the question and come a bit further on my own. however i still have problems and hope you can help me sir :)

Comment: where will you message me ?

Comment: @Brutiquzz Hi I am here... Did you try making a plunker?

Comment: sry i dont know what a plunker is :/

Comment: what i find highly peculiar about the above code is that it will allow me to make an image fly from indside the screen to outside the screen but not the inverse. do you know why that is ?

Comment: Define `inside` and `outside`... As far as I understand, the code should do what you expect...

Comment: okay

          var startPos = (currWidth / 2);
   var endPos = -1000;

this will make a picture go from indside the screen to outside the screen

but this:

          var startPos = -1000;
   var endPos = (currWidth / 2);

will make the image go from the start of the screen till further into the screen but never outside the screen. 

although in my eyes it should start from outside the screen aka -1000px

but it doens't

Comment: Okay. I will say, 0 to currWidth is inside and anything not in that range is outside. Do you agree?

Comment: So what exactly do you want now?

Comment: that it is not what is happening when i run the code. 

var startPos = -1000; var endPos = (currWidth / 2);

this should make it fly-in from startPos -1000px aka outside the screen where i cant see it yet. only when it reaches an endPos with a positive number should i be able to see it. 

From what i can judge the image starts in 0px and flys to (currWidth / 2); this makes no sense when it is supposed to fly in from -1000px